# how to plot combination of three parameters

Tags: testing, parameters, plot, matplotlib

My algorithm has three input parameters:

```
param1 in {0.1, 0.5, 1.0, 90, 95, +inf}
param2 in {10, 20, 30, 40, 60, 80, 100}
param3 in {0.01, 0.05, 0.10}
```

I ran tests for all combinations of those input values, resulting in different output. Output values are two: `# of rejected samples`, `# of non-rejected samples`. Clearly, the sum gives the total # of samples.

How can I plot all this to have a visual confirmation of which parameters yield the maximum `# of non-rejected samples / total # of samples` fraction?

I could use `matplotlib`, but I don't know how to proceed when there's more than one parameter involved.

Comment: Plotting multidimensional data is always a challenge.  Reducing the dimensionality is a common technique.  Another is to visualize it as a data cube.

Answer (score 0):

With any luck, you have results in a 3-dimensional array.  so long as param1 has a reasonable number of elements, I would use imshow like so:

```
max_val = 2000
plot_shape=(3,3)
for n, img in enumerate(data_cube):
    ax = subplot(plot_shape[0], plot_shape[1], n+1)
    title('Results for Param3=%0.3f'%param3[n])
    ax.set_xticks(range(len(params3)))
    ax.set_xticklabels([str(x) for x in params3])
    ax.set_yticks(range(len(params2)))
    ax.set_yticklabels([str(x) for x in params2])
    xlabel('param3')
    ylabel('param2')
    imshow(img, vmin=0, vmax=max_val)
```

Comment: Thank you, Carl. I don't understand your code, though. What is data_cube? where did my parameters go? I have results on different samples for all the combinations of the parameters mentioned above (values are exactly the ones shown)

Comment: data_cube is a 3-D array containing the results for each combination of your parameters.  The first dimension maps to param 1, the second maps to param2, and the third maps to param3.  I'll add some labels and maybe that will clear things up.